# How do I re-enable search from the menu bar?

Tags: linux-mint, firefox

I restored add-ons, bookmarks, and favorites from another installation (Manjaro) by copying the contents of `~/.mozilla/firefox/??????.default` into the correct folder of this installation.

Now, I cannot search from the address bar or the search pane in firefox.  Nor can I add a search provider from the firefox preferences window (below)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to reset firefox as detailed in their [tutorial](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings)
[image]
*However, it did not fix the problem immediately*.  My add-ons (xmarks and LastPass) were not re-enabled until I restarted firefox for another time (refresh was the first time).  Then, I discarded my xmarks settings and re-imported from a previous save.  **It was not clear to me if re-importing my xmarks settings or if just restarting the browser for the second time was the solution.**